# Glusterfs on Synology NAS?

Tags: ubuntu, cluster, network-attached-storage, glusterfs

I run a machine-learning cluster for my small business. The cluster consists of three Ubuntu servers. The 10TB `/home` directory, provided by Server 1, is shared across all servers and is almost full.

I'm thinking of adding additional storage. One idea is to buy a Synology NAS.

Say I buy a Synology of 20TB, how would I deal with the original 10TB from Server 1?

I feel it's best to combine Synology and the original 10TB, and make `/home` 30TB, but how would I do it?

Does it make sense to use Glusterfs?

https://lists.gluster.org/pipermail/gluster-users/2017-October/032718.html says "In theory, you can run GlusterFS on a Synology box ... In practice, you might be the first person to ever try it."

Is Synology bad for Glusterfs brick? What is the intended use for Glusterfs?

When I'm talking about Glusterfs, I'm open to use other distributed file systems, like BeeGfs.

Comment: Why not split them, i mean 10 TB of data are a huge amount for one device, what speaks against splitting?

Comment: @djdomi Currently the total size of /home partition is 10TB. What do you mean by spliting? Split by users, like each user is on his own partition?

Comment: i mean, you can have users also roamed to a other location, if you like to do so, and you have then i.e. /home /home2 or similar setup instead one big point of failure

Comment: And why bother with glusterfs anyway? Just move your data over to the Synology and export it via NFS which is probably what you're already doing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  how would I deal with the original 10TB from Server 1? If I bother with glusterfs, I can combine Synology and the original 10TB, getting 30 TB for my /home.

Comment: Put the disk in the Synology?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not ideal.. That requires disks of the same size for being in a RAID.

Comment: Then put it on eBay and buy correct sized disks.